# Configuring Sitecore to display PDFs in browser

Tags: configuration

Currently, when a user clicks on a PDF link on my site (served from the Media Library), the browser will download the PDF file. I'd like to change the behavior from downloading to opening in browser (I am aware that users can change their browser settings to force the behavior they want; I want to change the default behavior).

I know that I need to change the `Content-Disposition` response header to have `inline;` instead of `attachment;`. I could write a pipeline processor to change the `Content-Disposition` header, but I was hoping Sitecore had a setting for this specific behavior.

My site is currently on Sitecore 8.2 rev 161221.

Comment: I'm trying to reach a similar result to yours, but I'm currently unable to show the PDF link, I'm using Sitecore 9 and SXA 1.7, so i'm using rendering variants to show the pdf fields, but since the field type for the file is "File", it doesn't show anything on the page.. any advice on how to show that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `<mediaLibrary><mediaTypes>` section of Sitecore.config (or web.config in older versions of Sitecore) contains a `<mediatype>` element for each file type. Within each mediatype element is a `<forceDownload>` element. The `Content-Disposition` header will be set according to the value of the `forceDownload` setting; `attachment;` for true, `inline;` for false.

By default, `forceDownload` is set to `true` for PDFs. Changing this value to false will instruct browsers to view the file instead of download.

Comment: If you do this and it's still not working, make sure the line <mediaType extensions="pdf"><mimeType>application/pdf</mimeType></mediaType>
exists, and is not commented out in your app_config/Mimetypes.config

Comment: Any way to do this on a per file basis?

Comment: @ZacharyDow: I've not tried this, but you could probably use a custom pipeline to change the response headers before the media item response is sent.

Comment: @ZacharyDow please read my answer where I provided a simple solution to do this on a per file basis

Comment: It works with Sitecore 9.0.1 - Update 2 too. Thanks!

Comment: @EdSchwehm This is working like a charm. if multiple websites are in single sitecore instance, this is being applied to all websites. If I made this change specific to one website it's not working.

Answer (score 5):

You can also easily extend Sitecore to set `Content-Disposition` per file. To do this, add a new field on `File` template, located here `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned/File`. The best way is to create a new template and make `File` template to inherit from it.

The new field can be a checkbox named: `Set Content Disposition Inline`.

Then you have to create your own `MediaRequestHandler` and set it in `Web.config`. You can do that with transform file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_media.ashx" type="YourNamespace.MediaRequestHandler, AssemblyName" name="Sitecore.MediaRequestHandler" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(type)" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The last piece of course is `MediaRequestHandler`. You have to create a new class and inherit from existing one. This is how your class can looks like:

```
public class MediaRequestHandler : Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler
{
    protected override bool DoProcessRequest(HttpContext context, MediaRequest request, Sitecore.Resources.Media.Media media)
    {
        if (base.DoProcessRequest(context, request, media))
        {
            if (context.Response.StatusCode != 304)
            {
                if (media.MediaData.MediaItem.InnerItem[setContentDispositionFieldId] == "1")
                {
                    var extension = media.Extension;
                    if (extension.Length > 0 && extension[0] != '.')
                    {
                        extension = "." + extension;
                    }

                    var fileName = media.MediaData.MediaItem.Name + extension;

                    context.Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = $"inline; filename=\"{fileName}\"";
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this! base.DoProcessRequest sends the request so you can't modify the request headers after calling base.DoProcessRequest.

If you have a decompiler you can see what I am referring to.

Answer (score 1):

For Sitecore 9.x and above, follow the below steps to achieve this:

- Open the `App_Config/Sitecore.config` and go to `<mediaLibrary>` section. Change the Force Download for `<mediaType name="PDF file" extensions="pdf">` to false. By default, it is true.

```
<mediaType name="PDF file" extensions="pdf">
        <mimeType>application/pdf</mimeType>
        <forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
        <sharedTemplate>system/media/unversioned/pdf</sharedTemplate>
        <versionedTemplate>system/media/versioned/pdf</versionedTemplate>
      </mediaType>
```

I'd recommend creating a patch to make this change,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <!-- Force download of PDF files -->
    <mediaLibrary>
      <mediaTypes>
        <mediaType name="PDF file" extensions="pdf">
          <forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
        </mediaType>
      </mediaTypes>
    </mediaLibrary>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

- Open the `App_Config/MimeTypes.config` and uncomment the below line.

```
<mediaType extensions="pdf"><mimeType>application/pdf</mimeType></mediaType>
```