# Sitecore Forms Submit Action redirect to a PDF in Media Library

Tags: presentation, media-library, sitecore-forms

I have a form that, upon submission, should redirect and display a PDF from my media library. Upon submission, I am receiving this error:

[image]

Does Sitecore 9 Forms require that I provide a layout file for presenting PDFs?

Comment: No. I think you need to specify the pdf extension in the url: `.pdf` because Sitecore thinks it is an item with a layout that you want to render. Use the `GetMediaUrl()` to generate the url for the pdf and then perform the redirection

Comment: Thank you - the GetMediaUrl() was very helpful; however, the PDF is not being opened in the current window, it is instead being downloaded by the browser - how do I supersede this?

Comment: It is another question and you can check the link https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6046/configuring-sitecore-to-display-pdfs-in-browser. So i will post the comment as an answer since this is what was the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have the proper url for the `.pdf`, you need to use the method `GetMediaUrl`.

This will generates the url in the proper way. Moreover, you can check the following [answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6046/configuring-sitecore-to-display-pdfs-in-browser) on how to open or display the pdf on the browser.