# How to open pdf in browser instead of downloading in sitecore site?

Tags: pdf

I have referred the below link to make the pdf open in browser instead of downloading
[Configuring Sitecore to display PDFs in browser](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6046/configuring-sitecore-to-display-pdfs-in-browser)

The pdfs are still getting downloaded

I have done the below config changes, made the forcedownload option as false

**Sitecore.config**

```
<mediaType name="PDF file" extensions="pdf">
        <mimeType>application/pdf</mimeType>
        <forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
        <sharedTemplate>system/media/unversioned/pdf</sharedTemplate>
        <versionedTemplate>system/media/versioned/pdf</versionedTemplate>
      </mediaType>
```

**MimeTypes.config**

uncommented the below line

```
<mediaType extensions="pdf"><mimeType>application/pdf</mimeType></mediaType>
```

pdfs are still getting downloaded in chrome instead of opening in a new tab. In IE it opens in a tab.
Have also verified the setting in chrome for pdf download to be disabled.
Is there anything else missing ?

Comment: Could you please check showconfig.aspx once and verify the changes are reflecting. Just to make sure no cache issue.

Comment: Could you also check "developer tools" in Chrome to see which response headers are sent when you request a PDF file?

Comment: Is it a SXA site , custom pipeline ?forcedownload , this info also may be reqd

Comment: @AbhayDhar yes it is a SXA site, no custom pipeline is written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using the below patch configuration file for Sitecore 9.1 (Initial Release) and SXA 1.8 to stop the download of PDF files. It works fine for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <!-- Force download of PDF files -->
    <mediaLibrary>
      <mediaTypes>
        <mediaType name="PDF file" extensions="pdf">
          <forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
        </mediaType>
      </mediaTypes>
    </mediaLibrary>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Its worked for me after clearing the cache on sitecore server through admin/cache.aspx. My application is hosted on azure paas and CM n CD servers are different. Its working fine on CM after clearing cache, but not on CD as i dont have a option to clear cache. Any idea ?

Comment: try restarting the app services of CD

Comment: Thank you !! its working now

Comment: Google Chrome on Windows was a bit persistent. I had to clear the browser cache and close and re-open the browser to get this fix to be recognized.

Comment: @AbhayDhar  This is working like a charm. if multiple websites are in single sitecore instance and this has to be applied to a specific website. I made these changes to this patch config and its not working.

Comment: Maybe you can ask a new quest on SSE and get answers to that problem