# PDF files opening in browser rather than downloading

Tags: mediaurls

Have set the forcedownload to "true" -

```
<mediaType name="PDF file" extensions="pdf">
<mimeType>application/pdf</mimeType>
<forceDownload>true</forceDownload>
<sharedTemplate>system/media/unversioned/pdf</sharedTemplate>
<versionedTemplate>system/media/versioned/pdf</versionedTemplate>
</mediaType>
```

Have commented the mimetype line-

```
<!-- 
  <mediaType extensions="pdf"><mimeType>application/pdf</mimeType></mediaType>
   -->
```

But still the pdf file is opening in the tab , this is happening only on production site and not on other env , Can someone please help

Comment: are you getting any errors in log?

Comment: Can you confirm that your patch is being applied using showconfig.aspx?

Comment: Have you checked out this? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6046/configuring-sitecore-to-display-pdfs-in-browser

Comment: How is the download being triggered? Link in the UI? Direct viewing of a specific URL? Or do you want this to apply across the board no matter what? If UI, try adding a `download` attribute to the `<a>`.